# How to apply a style to a Python DataFrame for all rows except the last one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-styles

I am trying to apply a Bar Style to all of the data in the dataframe, except the last row, which is supposed to be the Total row.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), columns=list('AB'))
data.loc['Total'] = data.sum()

           A                B
0      -1.224620    -0.373898
1       0.75568      0.997875
2      -1.284663    -0.211903
3      -0.274813    -0.871816
4       1.256267    -0.742521
Total  -0.772143    -1.202263
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Bar Style"?

Comment: Something similar to df.stlye.bar(...) http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Other-Options.

Answer (score 2):

It was explained in the docs, that

> A tuple is treated as (row_indexer, column_indexer)

You just need to twist a bit the subset option.

On your data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), columns=list('AB'))
data.loc['Total'] = data.sum()

data.style.bar(subset = ([0,1,2,3,4], ['A', 'B']))
```

it gives

[image]